# How to auto close LWC quick action from JavaScript?

Tags: lightning-web-components, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

I have created a Lightning web component quick action for account object in the Summer 2021 sandbox org. This is the screen action and working fine, but I am not able to close the action using JavaScript. I know we can use `$A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();` in the Aura Components, but what is the Lightning web component equivalent for this?

I tried to find the documentations for this but seems to be not available at this time.

Comment: I've let the Salesforce docs team know about the missing page. If you need this functionality *today*, go with the Aura wrapper technique. If you can wait until they get back to you, should only be a few days, we'll probably have an affirmative answer.

Comment: @sfdcfox sure I will wait until few days

Comment: From the developer preview today, it looks like there is an undocumented "CloseActionScreenEvent" that hasn't made its way to the official docs yet, but I found an [RFC that references it](https://rfcs.lwc.dev/rfcs/lbc-api/0000-lwc-custom-quick-actions-api/revision/unknown). Check out BritishBoyinDC's answer.

Comment: New blog post references it now:
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/05/learn-moar-with-summer-21-lwc-quick-actions.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Per today's Summer 21 release webinar, you will need to do two things

Add a new import:

```
import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from 'lightning/actions';
```

Then add a simple method to close it:

```
closeQuickAction() {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
    }
```

You can then call that and it will close the quick action. More details [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/05/learn-moar-with-summer-21-lwc-quick-actions.html)

H/T to [Fabien Taillon](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/10350/fabien-taillon) for the heads up on this one

Comment: finally it came in the light of day, thanks

Comment: Anyone searching for related issue with this event https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/399185/96748.

Answer (score 10):

I found a workaround if you want to continue using the lwc quick action(as I do :)). You can use NavigationMixin and have it Navigate to the record page you're on.

```
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                 type: "standard__recordPage",
                 attributes: {
                    recordId: this.recordId,
                    objectApiName: "Account",
                    actionName: "view"
                 }
              });
```

I found it performs the same functionality as what an $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire().

Comment: Brilliant idea, thanks

Comment: Is there any refresh made to the page or it's only closing the popup?

Comment: @MartinLezer yes there is a refresh.

Comment: @RahulGawale thanks for the answer. I hope there will be a real feature for this in the future :(

Comment: I have not had success with this performing a refresh. Data updated by the action before closing the dialog does not show. Instead, I've resorted to: 
setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload(); }, 3000);

I don't like it, but it seems to work.