# Markup to present a spinner in a lightning-quick-action-panel quick action?

Tags: lightning-web-components, modal, spinner

Now that quick actions can be [created using LWCs](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/05/learn-moar-with-summer-21-lwc-quick-actions.html),
the [lightning-quick-action-panel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-quick-action-panel) component makes consistent styling easy:

```
<template>
    <lightning-quick-action-panel header={headerText}>
        <!-- fields and other content go here -->
        <div slot="footer">
            <!-- buttons go here -->
        </div>
    </lightning-quick-action-panel>
</template>
```

But I haven't managed to find a pattern for adding a [lightning-spinner](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-spinner/example) so that the spinner covers just the area of the modal including the footer. I've Googled and tried a number of placements. This [How to get a spinner on Quick Action LWC?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/348833/how-to-get-a-spinner-on-quick-action-lwc) does not provide any markup that solves the problem.

Is there a solution?

**PS**

The output I get using Damecek's suggestion:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: As an alternative, would it be an idea to disable the buttons when the spinner is loading? That might be easier to implement and sort of cleaner from UX standpoint

Comment: Hi @Raul, Thanks and that is what I am presently doing and seems good enough for when the component is loading. But the "Save" is quite time consuming so I'd like a spinner for that case.

Comment: another vote for disabling the button is looking at the normal quick action submit behavior. Button gets disabled and, if there's a loading icon, it's within the modal body only.

Comment: Exactly like what you mentioned - tried various suggestions, but the spinner just doesn't work right for me in the lightning-quick-action-panel tag. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Hi @goabhigo, No just living with it.

Answer (score 0):

In new quick-action-panel cmp I am using spinner as this. `slds-is-relative` will remove the ugly rectangular shadow and thanks to `style="min-height: 50vh"` the spinner will be visible whole.

```
<lightning-quick-action-panel header="asd">
    <div class="slds-is-relative" style="min-height: 50vh" if:true={spinner}>
       <lightning-spinner variant="brand"></lightning-spinner>
    </div>

</lightning-quick-action-panel>
```

Comment: I'll try that right now. Immediately inside the `lightning-quick-action-panel`? Putting it there or outside there the dialog expands vertically and the input fields are still active. So not a good result.

Comment: inside the lwc cmp

Comment: Not working for me.

Comment: how it looks like? update the question with a screenshot

Comment: Screen shot added to the question.

Comment: On my end, if you remove the style - just wrapping all the contents/body of the quick action in `div class="slds-is-relative"` covers the modal body nicely, but doesn't handle the footer as you asked. If you include the footer within that div, it won't display correctly.

Comment: and what about displaying the footer conditionally? if the spinner is displayed, then hide the footer with if:true

Comment: Hi @KrisGoncalves, Your approach for me eaves the spinner slightly under the model header and does not stop the fields from being focusable. But that general approach will work fine as I already have the buttons disabled.