# CloseActionScreenEvent bubbles

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, event, lightning-events

[Here](https://rfcs.lwc.dev/rfcs/lbc-api/0000-lwc-custom-quick-actions-api#screen-action-component-and-events) I've read that `CloseActionScreenEvent` does not bubble, but we can set in the constructor a `EventInit` object to force `bubbles = true`. So I have the following `this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent({bubbles: true}));`, but it does not work. What am I missing? I have parent used as the action and inside it a child which have the `lightning-quick-action-panel` component and I want to close the action from the child.

My current workaround for this is to dispatch a custom event from child and in parent, then handle it a dispatch the standard one to close the modal/action.

Comment: issue created https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/issues/2722

Comment: fix should be in place in winter 23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This finally works, but you need to set the `bubbles` and `composed` args like so.

```js
this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent({ bubbles: true, composed: true }));
```

Unfortunately I did not find any of this [documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_quick_actions_screen) anywhere.